# Find the general solution for this equation sin5θcos3θ = sin6θcos2θ.

Tags: trigonometry

I have tried to solve it but my is wrong. I did the following-

using
$$2\cos b\sin a = \sin(a+b) + \sin (a-b)$$

$$2\sin5\theta\cos3\theta = 2\sin6\theta\cos2\theta$$

$$\sin 8\theta+ \sin 2\theta = \sin8\theta+\sin4\theta$$

$$\sin2\theta - \sin4\theta = 0$$

$$\sin2\theta - 2\sin2\theta\cos2\theta=0$$

Case $1-$
$$\sin2\theta=0$$

$$\sin2\theta=\sin0$$

$\therefore$ $\theta = \frac{m\pi}{2}$

Case $2-$

$$2\cos2\theta =1 $$
$$\cos2\theta=\frac{1}{2}$$

$\therefore$ $\theta = n\pi \pm \dfrac\pi{6}$

So where I did wrong ????

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Why do you think its wrong?

Comment: The answer is $$\frac{2nπ}{3}\pm \frac{π}{6}$$ and $$mπ$$.

Answer (score 1):

$2\sin 5\theta \cos 3\theta =  2\sin 6\theta \cos 2\theta$

$\sin 8\theta + \sin 2\theta = \sin 8\theta + \sin 4\theta$

$\sin 4\theta - \sin 2\theta = 0$

$2\sin\frac{(4-2)\theta}{2} \cos \frac{(4+2)\theta}{2} = 0$

$\sin\theta = 0$ or $\cos 3\theta = 0$

$\theta = m\pi$ or $3\theta = (2n \pm 1)\pi/2$

$\theta = m\pi$ or $\theta = (2n \pm 1)\pi/6$

Comment: But in step 3 why didn't you used the identity of sin2$\theta$=2sin$\theta$cos$\theta$ ? Then Sin 4$\theta$ would change to 2sin2$\theta$cos2$\theta$.

Comment: Can anyone please explain me why he did that??

Comment: Please man is anyone there.

Comment: @somwoydipsarkar your answer of $\frac{m\pi}{2}$ is aloso correct. As we have both the sides as a product of $\cos$ and $\sin$, $\sin(m\pi) = 0$ or $\cos(\frac{m\pi}{2}) = 0$(if m is odd) or $\sin(\frac{m\pi}{2}) = 0$(if m is even) . So in simple, your answer is also correct. similarly second one is also correct.

Comment: But how can you explain more.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the solutions you have.

Your own solution has $$0, \frac \pi 2, \pi,  \frac {3\pi}2 \dots$$

and $$\frac \pi 6, \frac {5\pi}6, \frac {7\pi}6 \dots$$

The solution in the comments has $$0, \pi, 2\pi \dots$$

and $$\frac \pi 6, \frac \pi 2, \frac {5\pi} 6, \frac {7\pi}6, \frac {3\pi}2 \dots$$

The two solutions are therefore expressed differently, but return the same values - both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct. The sets $\{0,1,2,\dotsc\}$ and $\{0,2,4,\dotsc\}\cup\{1,3,5,\dotsc\}$ are the same, for instance.

Just check that each of your solution is in the proposed set and conversely.

There's even another way to express the same solution set.

When you are at
$$
\sin2\theta=\sin4\theta
$$
you can already conclude that either
$$
2\theta=4\theta+2m\pi
$$
or
$$
2\theta=\pi-4\theta+2n\pi
$$
that lead to
$$
\theta=m\pi
$$
or
$$
\theta=\frac{\pi}{6}+n\frac{\pi}{3}
$$